# Recently annouced plan for the implementation of zk-snarks into Tezos -timing?

Tags: protocol, upgrade, privacy

Apologies for this lay question but I would very much appreciate if anyone could kindly tell me (in plain English for lay people like me) the timeline for the implementation of zk-snarks into Tezos which has just been announced (as of 23rd October - please see below):

https://medium.com/tezoscommons/zk-snarks-and-fine-tuned-privacy-is-coming-to-tezos-77a4422ad991

Preliminary/estimated time line (at this stage) would be fine and greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in anticipation.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

This article has since been corrected!
The Sapling protocol has yet to be confirmed in the next proposal.
Have a look at this tweet: : https://twitter.com/TezosCommons/status/1189205247480066050